# how to tell how many times a user control is used and where is it used?

Tags: webforms

I would like to know how many times a user control is being used in a sitecore site.  If possible, I would like to get the list of pages that use a specific user control.  Googling doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the referrers of the specific user control since it's an item in Sitecore (rendering/sublayout) using the Link database.

For a quick check, you can take a look at the Navigate ribbon > Links

[image]

If you want a report-like list, it might be easiest to use [Sitecore Powershell Extensions](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/) to get a list of all referrers in an exportable format - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemreferrer